# tls connection failure in mosquitto

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I've generated certificates and able to make a successful connection using below command

```
mosquitto_sub -t "hello/world" -v --cafile ../certs/ca.crt --cert ../certs/client.crt --key ../certs/client.key
```

While I'm try to do the same with my code using same certificates, I'm facing following errors

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
LIBMOSQUITTO 1004005
8: Unable to connect: A TLS error occurred.
Success
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
1452241406: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1452241406: OpenSSL Error: error:140780E5:SSL routines:SSL23_READ:ssl handshake failure
1452241406: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Here is my code

```
int main(){
printf("LIBMOSQUITTO %d\n", LIBMOSQUITTO_VERSION_NUMBER);

        if ((m = mosquitto_new("rtr", 1, NULL)) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        int rc = mosquitto_tls_set(m,
                        "path/to/ca.crt",          /* cafile */
                        NULL,                   /* capath */
                        "/path/to/client.crt",             /* certfile */
                        "/path/to/client.key",             /* keyfile */
                        NULL                    /* pw_callback() */
                        );

        if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set TLS CA: %s (check path names)\n",
                                mosquitto_strerror(rc));
                exit(3);
        }
#if 0
        mosquitto_tls_opts_set(m,
                        SSL_VERIFY_PEER,
                        NULL,                   /* tls_version: "tlsv1.2", "tlsv1" */
                        NULL                    /* ciphers */
                        );
        mosquitto_tls_insecure_set(m, 1);
#endif
        if ((rc = mosquitto_connect(m, "localhost", 1883, 20)) != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: Unable to connect: %s\n", rc,
                                mosquitto_strerror(rc));
                perror("");
                exit(2);
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Also tested for port 8884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not called `mosquitto_lib_init()`.

Comment: Thanks. Is mosquitto_lib_init() only for encrypted connections. Because normal connections are working fine without initializing the libray.

Comment: Can you let me know what happens if I call lib_init() and lib_cleanup() multiple times. I'm writing wrappers for libmosquitto and want to hide these details from the user.

Comment: mosquitto_lib_init() calls everything that is needed by the internals of the library. If you're on Windows nothing will work without it for example. TLS is another example. You should always call it. Multiple calls - it depends whether anything else is using the same libraries (e.g. openssl). If you call lib_cleanup() then everything using openssl will stop working. I'd just do once at the beginning and once at the end if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is connecting to port 1883 which is typically not the TLS port; depending on what you've configured in `mosquitto.conf` I think you'll want port 8883, assuming you have a TLS listener configured at 8883.

I also point out that you use `/path/to` and `path/to` which may or may not be a copy/paste typo.